# $(window).load never called in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

In my Rails app, I've noticed that for certain pages that have a lot of images and videos, $(window).load never gets called when the page is loaded in Chrome.

I'm lazy-loading most of the images and videos on the page to try to mitigate the problem, but the pages do not load.

You can test it with this page, which will load fairly quickly in Firefox; in Safari, it takes a little longer but eventually loads.  With Chrome, it never loads.

http://buildinprogress.media.mit.edu/projects/2330/steps

This is what I have in my $(window).load:

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    console.log('loaded');

    // remove loading animation
    if($('#loading').css('display')!='none'){
        $('#loading').fadeOut(400, function(){
             $('#main').animate({opacity:1});
        });
    }else{
        $('#main').css('opacity',1);
    } 
    ...
 });
```

Comment: try `$(document).ready(function(){ /* ... */ })`

Comment: @shiyou unfortunately, that doesn't resolve the issue. If I just paste the loading fadeOut code in the console, you can see most of the images on the page are missing...

Comment: Try `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'){...}`

Comment: If you look at the network tab in Chrome, there are several resources that never finish loading (I see at least 4), thus all resources are not loaded and thus the `load` event does not fire. I can't find an explanation.  It appears like it might be a bug when lots of resources from the same domain are requested (which causes Chrome to hit its max limit for simultaneous requests).

Comment: thanks @jfriend00 I believe that's the issue but I have no idea how to start debugging it.

Comment: Could also possibly be an issue with the server hosting those resources too (some sort of concurrency issue).  I'd probably try to find the smallest number of resources from one source that demonstrates the problem and see what you learn trying to narrow it down that way.  Also, see if it is always resources from the same server that get stuck.